# How to move all lines that match x to the top of the file?

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

How do I move all lines of code that start with (or include) "@use" to the top of the file?

```
.css-class {
  @use 'text-size' as *; // How to move all lines starting with @use to the top of the file (Ideally alphabetizing them and removing duplicates as well)
  @include text-size(lg);
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.another-css-class {
  @use 'text-size' as *;
  @include text-size(md);
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  @use 'text-color' as *;
  @include text-color(dark);
}

.yet-another-css-class {
  @use 'background-color' as *;
  @include background-color(teal, 20);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Ideal output (bonus points for removing duplicates and alphabetizing the SASS imports)

```
@use 'background-color' as *;
@use 'text-color' as *;
@use 'text-size' as *; 


.css-class {
  @include text-size(lg);
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.another-css-class {
  @include text-size(md);
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  @include text-color(dark);
}

.yet-another-css-class {
  @include new--background-color(teal, 20);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Additional context:
I already have code that traverses a directory and goes line-by-line and adds a SASS import (`@use 'mixin-name' as *;`) above the mixins usage (`@include mixin-name();`). Ideally, I would like to add this to the top of the file, but am not having any luck.

I am open to other solutions that don't use node's fs.

add-sass-imports.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

const replaceFile = (file) => {
  const originalText = fs.readFileSync(file);
  const lines = originalText.toString().split("\n");
  const formattedLines = lines.map((line, lineNumber) => {
    const match = /.*@include\s([a-zA-Z'-]+)[\s(;]/.exec(line);

    if (!match) return line; // don't change anything

    const [, mixin] = match;

    //instead of adding it above the line, I would like it to be placed to the top of the file (and remove duplicates)
    return `@use '${mixin}' as *;
    ` + line;

  });

  fs.writeFileSync(file, formattedLines.join("\n"));
};

const replaceInFolder = (path) => {
  const content = fs.readdirSync(path);
  content.forEach((fileOrFolder) => {
    const fullPath = `${path}/${fileOrFolder}`;
    const stat = fs.statSync(fullPath);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      replaceInFolder(fullPath);
    } else if (fileOrFolder.endsWith(".scss")) {
      replaceFile(fullPath);
    }
  });
};

replaceInFolder("src/app")
```

Comment: @esqew, I attached the code to the bottom of my question. Most of it is from a co-worker, so I asked permisison if I could include it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in $(find . -name '*.scss')
do
        grep '@use\s' $file | sort -t: -k2,2 > $file.tmp
        grep -v '@use\s' $file >> $file.tmp
        mv $file.tmp $file
done
```

This grep code works.

Note: if you are using zsh, you can use `exec bash` to switch shells.